# Can't Run psql From Command Line After Adding To Path

Tags: macos, postgresql, shell, bash

I had Postgres installed on OSX. Postgres.app 9.5. I wanted PGAdmin so I uninstalled it thinking that was the way. I realized I needed the dependencies and pgadmin will just allow me a GUI to work with them. So After I had pgadmin installed I installed Postgres.app again. I added the bin path to pgadmin preferences.

At this point when I start the shell from the postgres.app I `\list` my Db and I can see the ones I have made.

Then I run pgadmin and I can see the same databases inside the GUI.

But I cant run psql from the command line.

Not in terminal 
Not in iTerm

When I paste this into the terminal I can start an active shell,

```
'/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin'/psql -p5432 -U postgres
```

But when I type this in terminal or iterm I get permission denied,

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin psql

zsh: permission denied: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin psql
```

When I run with sudo I get command not found.

I added this to my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin:$PATH"
```

Then I ran,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

I also quit out of terminal and iterm but when I run `psql` I still get command not found.

Any help from here would be great. I want to add psql to my path so I can do things like,

```
psql --Version
```

etc.

Comment: Is the space in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin psql` just a typo? Because there should be a slash instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I got it added to the path. I still have no clue why though. I have bash_profile - profile and zshrc and each one has a path specified in it. And when I update one of them it does not update my path instantly. It's like it is caching my path somewhere. Then sometimes it repeats my path. I got the problem sorted out but I think I have realized I have a much bigger problem with these three files not being updated correctly. Maybe I am going about it wrong.

Comment: You should read up on shells and their rc files in general. Some files get sourced whenever a shell starts (e.g. `.zhsrc` or `.bashrc`), while others oly get sourced in a so-called *login shell* (e.g. `.bash_profile`).